# Add a functionality in ant table

Tags: reactjs

In my application i use ant design. I want to add the delete row functionality in my table, but a came across some problems with the implementation. I want to add delete functionality functionality, but i can't do this because i can't render 2 `render` in

```js
{
      title: "operation",
      dataIndex: "operation",
      render: (text, record) => {    //first render
        const editable = isEditing(record);
        return editable ? (
          <span>
            <a
              href="javascript:;"
              onClick={() => save(record.key)}
              style={{ marginRight: 8 }}
            >
              Save
            </a>
            <Popconfirm
              title="Sure to cancel?"
              onConfirm={() => cancel(record.key)}
            >
              <a>Cancel</a>
            </Popconfirm>
          </span>
        ) : (
          <a disabled={editingKey !== ""} onClick={() => edit(record)}>
            Edit
          </a>
        ),
      }
       render: (text, record) =>    //second render
        data.length >= 1 ? (
          <Popconfirm
            title="Sure to delete?"
            onConfirm={() => handleDelete(record.key)}
          >
            <a>Delete</a>
          </Popconfirm>
        ) : null
    },
```

and i get `Duplicate declaration`. How to add delete functionality in my app and which is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is an error in setting data, in `handleDeleteMethod`
Change your handleDeleteMethod as follows

```
  const handleDelete = key => {
     setData(data.filter(item => item.key !== key));
  };
```

When you are using hooks, you need to pass the resultant new state that need to be set as a parameter, not the object like we use in `setState` method

Please feel free to ask doubts if any

**EDIT :**

For edit to work change the render as follows

```
render: (text, record) => {
    const editable = isEditing(record);
    return editable ? (
      <span>
        <a
          href="javascript:;"
          onClick={() => save(record.key)}
          style={{ marginRight: 8 }}
        >
          Save
        </a>
        <Popconfirm
          title="Sure to cancel?"
          onConfirm={() => cancel(record.key)}
        >
          <a>Cancel</a>
        </Popconfirm>
      </span>
    ) : (
      <>
        <a disabled={editingKey !== ""} onClick={() => edit(record)}>
          Edit
        </a>
        <Popconfirm
          title="Sure to delete?"
          onConfirm={() => handleDelete(record.key)}
        >
          <a>Delete</a>
        </Popconfirm>
      </>
    );
  }
```

Comment: but there is not anyore the edit functionality. You delete the first render, but how it will be with edit functionality?

Comment: I am sorry I din’t get you

Comment: sorry, you didn't delete. My question is next: as you can see in the question code snipet i have 2 renders. The first render should add `edit functionality` of the row, but now in `operation column ` i have only `delete` . How to add both?

Comment: when you pass two properties with same key in an object, the first one will be overrieded, so it will not work

Comment: it is not a problem if i will ask you to delete  the sandbox link and to leave only the script that you provide as an answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209263/discussion-between-askmen-and-sumanth-madishetty).

Comment: You want me to delete the sandbox link??

Comment: Deleted the sandbox link

Comment: i forgot something, won't be a problem if i will ask you one more thing? Could you delete the file and from your sandbox? II forgot to include in first question. Thank You

Comment: I don't find any point in what you are asking....Can't delete it right now, will do it later

Comment: @AskMen I deleted the sandbox